# How to submit prior art to contest application?

Tags: prior-art, us20110272920, ep2384964

[EP 2384964 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2384964A1) claims to be the foundation of split boards dating back to the early 1990's. Manufactures of Snowboards have been making woodcores with center plastic, bamboo and other impermeable materials. How would I submit prior art to assure a denial for this patent?

Comment: patent granted it would cost to raise objection now

Answer (score 1):

The patent has already granted in Europe as [EP 2384964 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2384964B1). However, there is a corresponding United States patent application, [US 2011/0272920](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110272920), that has not yet issued, so there is still time left to challenge it.

You can collect Prior Art in this community if you'd like (follow the instructions from [this question](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/a/146/14417)). These posts will be linked directly from Google Patents. If you want to submit Prior Art directly to the USPTO, please refer to [this answer](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/14417).